# Clean build before running Android application

Tags: android, eclipse, build

During my development under Android I saw that if I don't clean before building and running the application, it will keep some old files giving me no-sense errors since they were fixed one or two runs before.

Have you ever experienced this problem? Any idea of how to prevent it / how to clean always before running the application on Eclipse?

Comment: try under project tag in eclipse, there is one property "Build Automatically" make it true.

Comment: thanks, but it's already on true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not happen always. Most of the time if you not clear the project before build won't harm the application. I clear it form time to time, mostly when I change something in xml files, but for regular app checking I don't think you have to do it and I doubt that there is any method to clear before each build.

Comment: ah ok, I just thought that there was an option for that... thanks!